# dag.repo overwritten

Tags: centos, upgrade, data-recovery, repository

I accidentally overwrote dag.repo by trying to add this

```
[dag]
name=DAG RPM Repository
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

does anyone have the backup file for dag.repo which is found in /etc/yum.repos.d for centOS 5.8 or where can I download it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repo definition does not come with CentOS. But Dag's repo is mostly obsolete at this point; you should be using [Repoforge](http://repoforge.org/) instead.